# Hooking into the Notices Loop

Tags: extensions

I have an extension, and I'd like to walk users through the process of using it a little more. The process is:

- Installation
- Configuration
- Inserting Shortcode
- Creating Events

Right now, when a user installs the extension, if they go to Components | My Extension, I'm hooked into the message loop, I can enqueue messages directing them to the next steps.

What I would like to do is if they haven't taken the next steps to configure the extension, is show them a reminder to do that regardless of what they're doing in Joomla. IOW, regardless of what page they're on, if they haven't done X, I want to show them a message that reminds them to do X.

If someone could point me in the direction of how to do that, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run some code on each request you'll need a system plugin.  The php would look something like the following:

```
class plgSystemCheckConfiguration extends JPlugin
{
    function onAfterRoute()
    {
        // get a handle of the app from jfactory etc etc
        // check if they have done the config
        // if not enqueue a notice etc
    }
}
```

There's an overly complicated doc about making plugins here:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

There's a list of the system events and when they run here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System